# Tricky sql involving row compute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need to compute a field named Value below.

Calculation logic for `X0`: `X1/X2` `5/10` = `0.5`
Calculation logic for `Y0`: `Y1/Y2` `4/10` = `0.4`

Here is the sample data

```
ID Cd format Value
1  X1 #       5     
2  X0 %       0.5 --this needs to be computed based on X1/X2
3  X2 #       10
4  Y1 #       4     
5  Y0 %       0.4 --this needs to be computed based on Y1/Y2 
6  Y2 #       10
```

How do i write this in SQL

Thanks!!

Comment: x and y are just examples... how is the rule for the rest of the values?  is it one letter, followed by 0 1 2??? X0, Y0 exists, so this is an updtate query? or they do not exists in the table, so it is an insert?

Comment: Yes. Usually it's 0 = 1/2. It could be M0, M1, M2 or C0, C1, C2. Yes even sequence is correct 0,1,2. Can be update query or even select query with new value M0,X0,Y0 being said the M1,X1,Y1 & M2,X2,Y2 can remain same but M0,X0,Y0 is calculate based on values for M1/M2,X1/X2,Y1/Y2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes at least the existence of `x0` values at column `CD`. if that is not the case, an INSERT is needed, which is a bit different.

```
update u  set value  = p.value/q.value
from
theTable u
left join theTable p on left(u.CD, len(u.CD)-1)+'1' = p.CD   --  can be  left(u.CD, 1)+'1' = p.CD   if it is allways only one letter
left join theTable q on left(u.CD, len(u.CD)-1)+'2' = q.CD   --  can be  left(u.CD, 1)+'2' = q.CD   if it is allways only one letter
where right(u.CD,1) = '0'            -- if needed, you can also check CD lenght = 2
  and p.value/q.value  is not null   -- this avoids missing joins and dividing by 0
                                     -- but can be removed if null is desired for that case
```

Comment: let me know if it is clear and working, in other case, I will setup an sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pivot table:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES
   (1, 'X1', '#', 5  ),   
   (2, 'X0', '%', 0.5), --this needs to be computed based on X1/X2
   (3, 'X2', '#', 10 ),
   (4, 'Y1', '#', 4  ),   
   (5, 'Y0', '%', 0.4), --this needs to be computed based on Y1/Y2 
   (6, 'Y2', '#', 10 )

) AS x(id, cd, [format], [value]))

SELECT p.*, 1.0*[x1]/[x2] AS [x0], 1.0*[y1]/[y2] AS [y0]
FROM 
(SELECT cd, [value] FROM cte) AS c
PIVOT
(MAX([value])
FOR cd IN ([x1], [x2], [y1], [y2])) AS p
```

From there, if you need x0 and y0 in your table, it's a simple update away.